# Python/odoo - Magento Call/Request

Tags: python, magento, odoo, odoo-8, xml-rpc

Lets consider 'mywebsite' as my website uname as username and pwd as password.

Now the scenario is i have a system that was previously working but now when i am trying to connect to my magento from odoo it returns me an error

```
<ProtocolError for mywebsite/index.php/api/xmlrpc/: 301 Moved Permanently>
```

however this particular url ie https://mywebsite.com is accesible if you hit it on browser and also returns a true result when hit with **Postman**

i tried to hit the same url using a python script

```
import xmlrpclib
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://mywebsite.com')
session = server.login('uname','pwd')
```

Multiple times over multiple environments
when i execute this script from the same environment that my server is hosted upon i get the same error

```
Error 301 Moved Permenantly
```

Now when i hit the same above script from my local enviroment i get

```
SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

which i assumed arises due to using **https** so when i change the url with **http** i get same error back which is

```
xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for mywebsite.com/: 301 Moved Permanently>
```

Hitting the above scripts from a staging environment gets me the same result as my local enviroment

also when i change the above script and run it using ip of the website along with port i get

`socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`

then i tried changing the script and running it with this code

```
import urllib
print urllib.urlopen("http://mywebsite.com/").getcode()
```

when i run this code from my local machine i get

```
Error 403 Forbidden Request
```

Hitting this new code with ip of website with port gets me

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

When i hit this code **without** mentioning the **port** i get

```
SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

now hitting these code from live environment using mywebsite.com gets me

```
Error 403
```

using ip **without** the port

```
[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

**with** the  ip and port

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated 
if there are any silly mistakes please excuse them as i am a amateur in odoo/python

also if you have any other way to check if a url is hit-able please do let me know

Comment: This looks like a configuration/networking issue. You should try to ask your question here instead : https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sure will ask this quetion over there Thanks!

Comment: Downvoter may i know ur issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that when i entered the mywebsite url in odoo it was being appended in the backend by `/index.php/api/xmlrpc` which was working fine for some time 
but now due to some changes it doesnt accept index.php anymore as it is automatically routed(mayb)
anyways i solved the error by changing the appending string to `/api/xmlrpc`